# React Native - How to list suggestions of my own component props?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to show all of my props when calling the component from parent,

I have a component called `Loader.js` and the list of props is like below:

```
static propTypes = {
  nameLoader: PropTypes.string,
  typeSpinner: PropTypes.string
}

static defaultProps={
  typeSpinner:'ThreeBounce'
}
```

and when I called the component from my parent, I want to know the list of my props, just like when I see the component of facebook like this

[image]

but I can't see the list suggest of my own component props

There's a way to archive it?

Comment: use typescript and define you props

Comment: can you provide me some simple code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]Use typeScript define you props like

```
interface IHelloFormProps {
    name: string;
    handleChange(event: any): void; }

interface IHelloContentProps {
    name: string; }
```

Pass this interface type defined props

```
export default class HelloForm extends React.Component<IHelloFormProps, any> {
    constructor(props: IHelloFormProps) {
        super(props);
    }

    public render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input 
                    value={ this.props.name }
                    onChange={ e => this.props.handleChange(e) }
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

[boilerplate](https://github.com/rokoroku/react-redux-typescript-boilerplate)

Comment: this works on vscode and it also requires some extension to use

Comment: thanks sir, your code help me out the problem, i'm using vsCode too, but the `typeScript` code give me red at text file [error typing code] that i think vsCode check the typeScript like JS, do you have an extensions to handle the red text of typescript?

Comment: @flix I didn't get your problem. may be due to lint check its configuration and disable those

Comment: it's ok sir, but how do you define default value if i used `typeSpinner?: 'CircleFlip' | 'Bounce'`?